# Sorting a linked list- why not?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was recently reading an [article](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-that-job-at-google.html) which mentioned:

> For God's sake, don't try sorting a linked list during the interview.

Is there any reason why the author wrote this? The reason is not immediately clear. I am aware that merge sort works on linked lists in O(nlgn) time- what's wrong with that? Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT:**
Any reason why is question is voted to close? I'm honestly curious and merely looking for some answers or interesting points.

Comment: I can't read Steve's mind. Why don't you leave a comment at his blog and ask him.

Comment: or why don't i consult the good folks of SO for their humble opinion? if inconclusive, i shall be sure to leave a comment there.

Comment: It's one person who doesn't feel confident enough in his own abilities (or who underestimates the abilities of others) in this particular respect. If you feel you could implement a sort on a linked list at the whiteboard - I believe I could - then by all means, do so.

Comment: The question is being voted to close because, as @DavidHeffernan says, we can't read the author's mind. You might have better luck on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have no way of knowing why the author of the blog wrote what he did. If I had to guess, I'd say what was really meant was something along the lines of:

> Don't assume that efficiently sorting a linked list would be as easy as sorting a data structure that provides random access to its elements. If you do end up relying on being able to sort a linked list, be prepared to explain what a suitable algorithm might be, and to discuss its complexity.

Answer (score 17):

I think you'll find that, although it's possible to sort a linked list using merge sort, the code to do so efficiently is somewhat involved. It's not something you'd want to develop while standing at the white board in the middle of an interview.

Comment: Unless you have read the relative chapters at TAOCP and you feel confident to impress the audience.

Comment: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html

Comment: Like it depends on you if you should do it or not? If the interviewer asks you to sort a linked list you will sort it. If not, why would you do it just for fun in an interview?

Answer (score 1):

The operation of getting/setting elements at specific indices is used by most sorting algorithms, and are required to be fast in order for the sorting algorithms to be fast. Normally they are `O(1)` for say a normal list, but for a linked list it is `O(n)` and this makes the sorting terribly inefficient. Perhaps this captures the reasoning behind your quote.

Comment: Sorting a linked list doesn't require indexed access. A merge sort, which accesses items sequentially, is quite efficient, although not as fast as Quicksort. The code, however, is somewhat involved.